# BizTalk XMLReceive promote properties not for all debatched messages

Tags: biztalk

I have a problem with my BizTalk solution: not all debatched MessageState messages contain correlationId property

[image: some debatched messages contain correlationId]

[image: but another messages doesn't contain correlationId]

My solution has document schema (GetMessageStateSchema.xsd), envelope schema (GetMessageStateEnvelopeSchema.xsd) and two document property schemas (GetMessageStatePropertySchema.xsd in the same project, PropertySchema.xsd in referenced project).

Message types: MessageState - document type from GetMessageStateSchema.xsd, MessageStateEnvelope - envelope type from GetMessageStateEnvelopeSchema.xsd

MessageState has three promoted properties: MessageId - property from GetMessageStatePropertySchema.xsd, Status - property from GetMessageStatePropertySchema.xsd, correlationId - property from PropertySchema.xsd

MessageId and correlationId have the same path to extract value from MessageState body

GetMessageStateSchema.xsd:

```xsl
<xs:schema xmlns="http://test-project1" xmlns:ns1="https://TestProject1.Biztalk.Schemas.PropertySchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="http://test-project1/properties" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://test-project1" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo root_reference="MessageState" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
      <b:imports>
        <b:namespace prefix="ns0" uri="http://test-project1/properties" location=".\GetMessageStatePropertySchema.xsd" />
        <b:namespace prefix="ns1" uri="https://TestProject1.Biztalk.Schemas.PropertySchema" location="TestProject1.Biztalk.Schemas.PropertySchema" />
      </b:imports>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="MessageState">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:properties>
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageState' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']/*[local-name()='MessageId' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']" />
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageState' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']/*[local-name()='State' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']" />
          <b:property name="ns0:State" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageState' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']/*[local-name()='State' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']" />
          <b:property name="ns1:correlationId" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageState' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']/*[local-name()='MessageId' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']" />
          <b:property name="ns0:MessageId" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageState' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']/*[local-name()='MessageId' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']" />
          <b:property distinguished="true" xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageState' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']/*[local-name()='Description' and namespace-uri()='http://test-project1']" />
        </b:properties>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MessageId" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Description" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

GetMessageStateEnvelopeSchema.xsd:

```xsl
<xs:schema xmlns="hhttp://test-project1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="hhttp://test-project1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation=".\GetMessageStateSchema.xsd" />
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" root_reference="MessageStateEnvelope" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="MessageStateEnvelope">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='MessageStateEnvelope' and namespace-uri()='hhttp://test-project1']" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="MessageState" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

GetMessageStatePropertySchema.xsd:

```xsl
<xs:schema xmlns="http://TestProject1.BizTalk.Schemas.GetMessageStatePropertySchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="http://test-project1/properties" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://test-project1/properties" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="property" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="MessageId" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="a2c00b01-ce8e-4052-aef4-ecf018d7566e" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="e9d31718-23a4-41dc-b4a4-635334de7a88" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

PropertySchema.xsd:

```xsl
<xs:schema xmlns:mdm="http://test-project2/properties" xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="https://TestProject2.Biztalk.Schemas.PropertySchema" xmlns="http://TestProject2.Biztalk.Schemas.PropertySchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://TestProject2.Biztalk.Schemas.PropertySchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation=".\Types.xsd" namespace="http://test-project2" />
  <xs:import schemaLocation=".\SimpleTypes.xsd" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo schema_type="property" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
      <b:references>
        <b:reference targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
        <b:reference targetNamespace="http://test-project2" />
      </b:references>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="correlationId" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:fieldInfo propertyGuid="d659a31d-c943-4465-9409-e8c371aaff5f" propSchFieldBase="MessageDataPropertyBase" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Input envelope:

```xml
<MessageStateEnvelope xmlns="http://test-project1">
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>32983DE3-6984-4E43-835A-464EAD74BEC6</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>EE08D44A-79C3-4740-AB64-3C1FBB9F65A5</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>4D820BC6-D6CA-4CF1-8CE4-79A6A900F715</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>2CBE4C76-1E1B-49BA-A502-A7E1C708BEF9</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>B3993229-5369-4965-9C78-50F554BE2759</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>EBD836B8-64B9-4591-8CBD-EE5F10CCF9DC</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>8C2EAE52-6052-46EE-9222-CE2E9EDA156D</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>C7D9DACB-FDE2-48C6-825C-324AB6BCDCE8</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>732F1940-6227-4DEA-972C-6A9CACCC86A9</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>3C4C1269-19AA-4AFD-9477-687159DF6B32</MessageId>
        <State>success</State>
        <Description xsi:nil="true"/>
    </MessageState>
    <MessageState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <MessageId>AC0850E5-0796-4F60-AFD6-38A1DC31C053</MessageId>
        <State>error</State>
        <Description>some error description</Description>
    </MessageState>
</MessageStateEnvelope>
```

PS:

[image: standard XMLReceive pipeline]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - please review the [guidelines on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this will help you to get useful answers to your question

Comment: For starters the messages you are showing us are the Routing Failure Report messages so first you need to work out why your debatched messages aren't being routed to a send port group, send port or Orchestration. Maybe set up a dummy send port with a simple filter (e.g. receive port name), and look at the properties of the actual message.

Comment: I know about that. I have the orchestration which requires correlationId property to corellate MessageState messages into it. But MessageState haven't promoted correlationId.

Comment: I solve the problem. Distinguished field MessageId which has the same xpath has been removed. After that correlationId starts to be promoted to all debatched MessagesState messages. But I don't remember any limitations for promoted properties and distinguished fields with same xpath